# Login form can't be validated in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm creating a simple login page with name and email as their fields. Have defined a certain set of rules in the `UserForm.php` file but as the end result, the rules aren't getting applied.

This is my Model class.
UserForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class UserForm extends Model 
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                [['name','email'],'required'],
                ['email','email'],
            ];  
    }
}
```

This is SiteController class.

```
public function actionUser()
  {
    $model = new UserForm;
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Data Entered');
    }

    return $this->render('userForm',['model'=>$model]);
  }
```

This is my view file
userForm.php

```
<?php


use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php 
    if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success'))
    {
        echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
    }
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email'); ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

Comment: First thing, make sure your form ends with `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>`. Secondly, what happens when you click submit?

Comment: What behavior right now do you have? can you explain? after submit and before submit?